# E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Tags: apt, updates, apache2, mysql, php

I am using ubuntu 13.10 on evaluation board and my internet is not working. Also i need to install softwares and apt-get install is also not working.

Terminal says :  E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

source : http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-apache2-with-php5-and-mysql-support-on-ubuntu-13.04-lamp

Comment: `apt-get` gets files from the internet and installs them, so if your internet is not working then it won't be able to fetch the files.

Comment: Unless he was getting a `404` error, then getting back to the grid is the exact solution.

Answer (score 48):

Run `sudo apt-get update` command.

If `sudo apt-get update` is also not working then follow the steps below:-

1. Open `/etc/apt/sources.list` file.
2. Check the word after `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` in the `sources.list` file, let the word be `xyz`
3. Go to the address `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/` and then click on dists. Now check whether `xyz` is present at this path. If it is not present, then replace `xyz` with the element which is present in 'dists' such as:- saucy, lucid, trusty etc.
4. Now run `sudo apt-get update` command.

Regards

Sanjay Sharma

Comment: worked for me, I used to replace 'raring' by 'trusty' and most of the problem solved.

Comment: I did not get any entry containing "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/" in source.list file.

Comment: In my case:
"http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu" -> "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/trusty/"
in the /etc/apt/sources.list file fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 44):

Just type

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

(and re-install)

Comment: nice it works, but what does this command do?

Comment: Simple yet effective