# Ubuntu Docker image - unable to fetch archives with apt-get

Tags: apt, updates, docker

I've been trying to build a docker image using Ubuntu:16.04 as the base image. I want to install python so I use

```
RUN \
apt-get -y update && \
apt-get -y install python python-dev python-pip
```

on a single `RUN` command to avoid layer caching. I also have tried using the `--no-cache` flag in my build command, but it does not prevent the error

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/manpages/manpages-dev_4.04-2_all.deb  Writing more data than expected (2078445 > 2047608)
Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I looked at other [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364404/e-unable-to-fetch-some-archives-maybe-run-apt-get-update-or-try-with-fix-mis), and as this is a docker image I can't access `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: Also related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

Comment: I added a `RUN sed -i 's/http:\/\/lt\./http:\/\//g' /etc/apt/sources.list` line to my docker file, but it seems to make no difference.