# Package Installation Problems

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center, deb

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and when I open .deb files, it opens Ubuntu Software. When I press the install button in Ubuntu Software, it opens a "waiting to install" process and never installs.

The output for `sudo apt install /home/potato/Downloads/discord-0.0.4.deb`:

```
potato@Potato:~$ sudo apt install /home/potato/Downloads/discord-0.0.4.deb
[sudo] password for potato: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'discord' instead of '/home/potato/Downloads/discord-0.0.4.deb'
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libappindicator1 libc++1 libindicator7
Suggested packages:
  clang
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  discord libappindicator1 libc++1 libindicator7
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 21.9 kB/47.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 146 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 /home/potato/Downloads/discord-0.0.4.deb discord amd64 0.0.4 [47.6 MB]
95% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com]                                      
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libindicator7 amd64 12.10.2+16.04.20151208-0ubuntu1
  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libindicator/libindicator7_12.10.2+16.04.20151208-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

output for `dpkg -i`

`sudo dpkg -i /home/potato/Downloads/discord-0.0.4.deb
Selecting previously unselected package discord.
(Reading database ... 244590 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../Downloads/discord-0.0.4.deb ...
Unpacking discord (0.0.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of discord:
 discord depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.
 discord depends on libc++1; however:
  Package libc++1 is not installed.`

`dpkg: error processing package discord (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 discord`

Comment: Can you open a terminal and run `sudo apt install PATH/TO/YOUR.deb`? Does that work? If not, please [edit] your question and add the full output you get.

Comment: What are you trying to install? Is your goal to use Ubuntu Software for this, or just to get your .deb files installed? Besides what Byte Commander has suggested, I also sugget trying `sudo gdebi your-file.deb`, where `your-file.deb` is replaced with your actual filename. Before running either that `apt` command or the `gdebi` command I've suggested, you should cancel the installation process in Ubuntu Software (if you can) and it would be best to exit Ubuntu Software, too. Please include this information, if possible, in your **[edit]**, including the complete output of all commands you run.

Comment: you can also do `dpkg -i PATH/TO/YOUR.deb`; however, dpkg does not handle dependencies. I think the other two suggestions do.

Comment: Your core issue is this one: `Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'`.  This indicates an issue with your network connection or setup, because it can't figure out where the archive mirror actually sits (aka a DNS problem)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [" Unable to fetch some archives" when trying to install phpmyadmin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/416930/unable-to-fetch-some-archives-when-trying-to-install-phpmyadmin) and [E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364404/e-unable-to-fetch-some-archives-maybe-run-apt-get-update-or-try-with-fix-mis)