# Unable to fetch some archives - recently modified ubuntu package sources

Tags: 18.04, package-management, updates, source-packages

I tried to install some package, because I think it does not matter here, let it be:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev libxml2-dev
```

but the output I receive is:

```
Err:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0 amd64 1.7.2-1ubuntu1
  500  Internal Error [IP: 10.158.100.3 8080]
Err:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 icu-devtools amd64 60.2-3ubuntu3
  500  Internal Error [IP: 10.158.100.3 8080]

# ...

E: Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/harfbuzz/gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0_1.7.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  500  Internal Error [IP: 10.158.100.3 8080]
E: Failed to fetch http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/icu/icu-devtools_60.2-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb  500  Internal Error [IP: 10.158.100.3 8080]

# ...

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So I checked the `/etc/apt/sources.list` according the answer of [Sanjay](https://askubuntu.com/users/307672/user307672) to [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364404/e-unable-to-fetch-some-archives-maybe-run-apt-get-update-or-try-with-fix-mis), but it looks like all my sources list are present in http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/.

One thing I am curious is, today is 31.10.2019T09:44 and last modification of `bionic-xxx` sources, which I have in my `sources.list` file is from two hours ago (31.10.2019T07:33). Is it possible that something went wrong with this modification?

If yes, where should I raise an issue on that?

If no, what else should I check/modify?

EDIT:
I saw similar questions. I asked a new one, because of 500s on source updated 1 hour ago seemed not right to me, and wasn't aware that changing mirror is the solution.

Comment: 500 means that there's an error on the server side, try switching mirror and run `sudo apt update` right after.

Comment: Thanks Yaron, switching mirrors from `pl` to i.e. `de` in all places helped

Comment: Care if I'll add an answer so you can mark is as solved?

Comment: @Yaron, please do add an answer, so I could mark it. Btw. I wondered why you didn't add answer instead of a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 means that there's an error on the server side, try switching mirror and run `sudo apt update` right after.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Yaron](https://askubuntu.com/users/46939/yaron) suggests in comment, 500's were the issue, not wrong source. Switching all mirrors from `http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` to i.e. `http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` helped.